# Add Selenium Android Studio

Tags: java, android, maven, selenium, android-studio

I am trying to install Selenium web driver in, my Android Studio Project, but can't get it to work, when I try and run I just get couple errors, saying that libs are not found. Here is what I have tried so far, I found this tutorial on how to do it in eclipse and tried to do it in Android Studio by just all all the .jar files to my life file and then adding them as a library but that didn't work. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/826914/How-to-Setup-and-Configure-Selenium-Webdriver-With (that is tutorial)

I have also looked on SO and haven't found any answers to this question and have also googled this and looked on the selenium website and found this http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_installing_java_driver_Sel20_via_maven.jsp#importing-maven-into-intellij-reference, but I can't make any sense of what they are trying to tell me to do.

If anyone has done this, or know how to install I would really appreciate the help.

Here I complile Libraires

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.2'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
compile project(':facebook')
compile files('libs/selenium-java-2.45.0.jar')
compile files('libs/selenium-java-2.45.0-srcs.jar')
}
```

I get `Gradle Build finished with 101 errors` that look like this

[image]

Comment: `that didn't work.` post the part of your gradle file where you declared those libraries

Comment: If you're missing some libs then you can use this to find the Gradle dependencies and include them: http://gradleplease.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Import using `implementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.0"` in your app level `build.gradle`